# Scala F-bounded polymorphism on object

Tags: scala, object, f-bounded-polymorphism

I cannot write the following F-bounded polymorphism in Scala. Why?

```
trait X[T <: X[T]]
object Y extends X[Y]
```

How can I express this and make it compile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It really seems like you ought to be able to write,

```
trait X[T <: X[T]]
object Y extends X[Y.type]
```

however, if you try that the compiler will give you an unhelpful (and I think spurious) error,

```
scala> object Y extends X[Y.type]
<console>:16: error: illegal cyclic reference involving object Y
       object Y extends X[Y.type]
```

I say "spurious" because we can construct an equivalent object with a little bit of additional infrastructure,

```
trait X[T <: X[T]]

trait Fix { type Ytype >: Y.type <: Y.type; object Y extends X[Ytype] }
object Fix extends Fix { type Ytype = Y.type }
import Fix.Y
```

If you wanted to experiment with this in real code, using a package object in place of `object Fix` would make this idiom a little more usable.

Comment: Do you think this is a compiler bug or is it an oversight in the spec? Or maybe there is some subtlety we're not seeing which makes the error necessary?

Comment: A conversation with @retronym on [scala/scala](https://gitter.im/scala/scala?at=55dc7303fcfd5a7865af45d4) suggests it's a bug. And it [works as expected on Dotty](https://gitter.im/lampepfl/dotty?at=55dc95a3a6bcd8894068e278).

Answer (score 1):

Change it to :

```
  trait Y extends X[Y]
```

`object` is not a type in Scala, but the so called companion object.
By defining `object Y`, you can't express that it should extend `trait T[Y]`, since that second `Y` refers to a type `Y` that hasn't been defined. 
You can however do the following:

```
trait Y extends X[Y]          //If you try this on the REPL, do :paste before
object Y extends X[Y]
```

In this case the object `Y` extends `X[Y]` where the second Y is the trait you just define, make sure you keep this in mind.

Comment: I would like Y to be instanciated only once and access its unique instance, that's why I need an object.

Comment: Then you can make the constructor private with `class Y private() extends X[Y]` and just make that one instance publicly available.