# Scala class singleton with non-default constructor parameters

Tags: scala, constructor, companion-object, callbyname

I have already read about issues with objects inheriting from companion classes.

For example:

- [Class constructor parameter with default value causes companion object initializer to fail](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5000)
- [super constructor cannot be passed a self reference unless parameter is declared by-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996199/super-constructor-cannot-be-passed-a-self-reference-unless-parameter-is-declared)

But I have a bit different issue (I am not sure that it is a bug)

I have the following code:

```
class Scala(name: String)

import Scala._

object Scala extends Scala(TEST_NAME){
  val TEST_NAME = "test name"
}
```

Note, that I am using variable defined in scope of companion object and then passing it to super's constructor.

I am getting the following compilation error:

```
Scala.scala:5: error: super constructor cannot be passed a self reference 
unless parameter is declared by-name

object Scala extends Scala(TEST_NAME){
                           ^
one error found
```

Other variants that I have tried:

Call by name:

```
class Scala(name: => String)

import Scala._

object Scala extends Scala(TEST_NAME){
  val TEST_NAME = "test name"
}
```

Named argument:

```
class Scala(name: String)

import Scala._

object Scala extends Scala(name = TEST_NAME){
  val TEST_NAME = "test name"
}
```

Both of them:

```
class Scala(name: => String)

import Scala._

object Scala extends Scala(name = TEST_NAME){
  val TEST_NAME = "test name"
}
```

Some environment details:

- java:  `java version "1.8.0_144"`
- javac: `javac 1.8.0_144`
- scala: `Scala code runner version 2.12.3`
- scalac: `Scala compiler version 2.12.3`
- OS: `Darwin ***.local 17.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.0.0: Thu Aug 24 21:48:19 PDT 2017; root:xnu-4570.1.46~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`

Update:

For anyone who is interested in resolution of this:

- [scala/bug/10537](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10537)
- [Scala users discussion](https://users.scala-lang.org/t/issue-scala-class-singleton-with-non-default-constructor-parameters/1742)

Comment: I don't think companionship plays any role here

Comment: @EduardoParejaTobes you mean there is no need in companionship, yes?

Comment: yup, that this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/32203867/614394 but for values. I think it's fine for types, and wrong for values :)

Comment: There is some sense in such kind companions. For example: `scala.util.Random`. Or when you have DTO that returns static data, e.g. description of service, terms of use, etc.

Comment: I meant not about companions extending the class/trait they accompany, but about an object having "access to itself" when extending any other class/trait. I think its type should be accessible (so that you can write `object X extends Y[X.type]`), but its values not.

Answer (score 2):

For your restricted use case:

```
scala> class C(s: String) ; object X extends C(X.x) { final val x = "hello, world" }
defined class C
defined object X
```

The constant value definition is inlined (per the spec).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an obscure feature that is going to be removed in Scala 3: early initializers. It allows you to specify init code to run before you call superclass constructor.

```
class Scala(name: String)

object Scala extends {
  val TEST_NAME: String = "test name"
} with Scala(TEST_NAME) { /* rest of object code */ }
```

Note that import is not required - `TEST_NAME` is already in the scope.

---

Here's a [Scastie snippet](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/QT0NDjXwRXGTBa1hxdogew) to prove that it works.

Comment: Thank you for answering. So what is the resolution of my question? Is it a bug? Edge case?

Comment: @AndriiAbramov I don't know. I'd call a bug that by-name parameter isn't working while the message suggests that it should (esp. if older versions of Scala supported that, which I cannot check now), but it's probably enough of an edge case too, since nobody seemed to care for at least since 2.10.

Answer (score 0):

If your code above would compile then you could write

```
class A(val x: String)

object B extends A(B.x_again) {

  val x_again = x
}
```

which certainly doesn't look good.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that it looks a bit strange.